# ASP.NET MVC 2 InputExtensions different on server than local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So this is kind of a crazy problem to me, but I've had no luck Googling it.  I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 application (under .NET 4.0) running locally just fine.  When I upload it to my production server (under shared hosting) I get

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TheActivityTracker.Resident>' does not
> contain a definition for 'TextBoxFor' and no extension method
> 'TextBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type
> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TheActivityTracker.Resident>' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

for this code:

```
<%= this.Html.TextBoxFor(person => person.LastName) %>
```

This is one of the new standard extension methods in MVC 2.  So I wrote some diagnostic code:

```
       System.Reflection.Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(InputExtensions));

       Response.Write("From GAC: " + ass.GlobalAssemblyCache.ToString() + "<br/>");
       Response.Write("ImageRuntimeVersion: " + ass.ImageRuntimeVersion.ToString() + "<br/>");
       Response.Write("Version: " + System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(ass.Location).ToString() + "<br/>");
       
       foreach (var method in typeof(InputExtensions).GetMethods())
       {
           Response.Write(method.Name + "<br/>");
       }
```

running locally (where it works fine), I get this as output:

```
From GAC: True
ImageRuntimeVersion: v2.0.50727
Version: File: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll InternalName: System.Web.Mvc.dll OriginalFilename: System.Web.Mvc.dll FileVersion: 2.0.50217.0 FileDescription: System.Web.Mvc.dll Product: Microsoft® .NET Framework ProductVersion: 2.0.50217.0 Debug: False Patched: False PreRelease: False PrivateBuild: False SpecialBuild: False Language: Language Neutral
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBoxFor
CheckBoxFor
CheckBoxFor
Hidden
Hidden
Hidden
Hidden
HiddenFor
HiddenFor
HiddenFor
Password
Password
Password
Password
PasswordFor
PasswordFor
PasswordFor
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButtonFor
RadioButtonFor
RadioButtonFor
TextBox
TextBox
TextBox
TextBox
TextBoxFor
TextBoxFor
TextBoxFor
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
GetType
```

and when running on the production server (where it fails), I see:

```
From GAC: True
ImageRuntimeVersion: v2.0.50727
Version: File: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll InternalName: System.Web.Mvc.dll OriginalFilename: System.Web.Mvc.dll FileVersion: 2.0.50217.0 FileDescription: System.Web.Mvc.dll Product: Microsoft® .NET Framework ProductVersion: 2.0.50217.0 Debug: False Patched: False PreRelease: False PrivateBuild: False SpecialBuild: False Language: Language Neutral
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
Hidden
Hidden
Hidden
Hidden
Hidden
Hidden
Password
Password
Password
Password
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
RadioButton
TextBox
TextBox
TextBox
TextBox
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
GetType
```

note that "TextBoxFor" is not present (hence the error).

I have MVC referenced in the csproj:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>References\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Upon user Levi's suggestion, I uploaded and ran the MvcFutures' diagnostics page - here's the innocent looking output:

```
Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Diagnostics Information

This page is designed to help diagnose common errors related to mismatched or conflicting ASP.NET MVC binaries. If a known issue is identified, it will be displayed below in red text.

For questions or problems with ASP.NET MVC or this utility, please visit the ASP.NET MVC forums at http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx.
Environment Information

Operating system: Microsoft Windows NT 6.0.6002 Service Pack 2
.NET Framework version: 4.0.30319.1 (32-bit)
Web server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Integrated pipeline: True
Worker process: w3wp.exe
ASP.NET MVC Assembly Information (System.Web.Mvc.dll)

Assembly version: ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM (2.0.50217.0)
Full name: System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Code base: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Mvc/2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Mvc.dll
Deployment: GAC-deployed
ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly Information (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll)

An ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly has not been loaded into this application. If desired, you can download ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM Futures from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183739.
All Loaded Assemblies

50 assemblies are loaded.

    * A_d509bf65_3d32_48f0_8ab6_566e289003a6, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    * Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    * App_global.asax.5qqlf9ir, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    * App_Web_2vnklzay, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    * App_Web_n3cjbc0f, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    * App_Web_v3sxbd4u, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    * DotNetPanel.IIsModules, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f9c58a0aa32ff0
    * Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * Microsoft.JScript, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.Runtime.DurableInstancing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    * System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
    * System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    * TheActivityTracker, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Diagnostics version: 02/16/2010 00:00:00 v7
Report generated on: 05/05/2010 18:12:56
```

I just can't figure it what to do next.  Thoughts?

Thanks!

-Mike

Comment: questions this old and frankly irrelevant now. cant they moved to an archive?? or closed?? it has no answer. sludge clogging the pipes

Answer (score 1):

Your hoster is running a prerelease version of MVC 2.  (Even worse, they seem to have GACed it!)  They might also be running a prerelease version of the .NET 4 Framework.

Call them and tell them to upgrade to the RTM builds. :)

Comment: Or reference a local copy of the System.Web.Mvc reference.  Probably easier than dealing with the host.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time referencing a local copy of System.Web.Mvc, as the GACed version will always win over the local copy.  You could try getting the MVC sources and recompiling it with a different version number, I suppose.  Regardless, you really should contact the host and get them to fix it.  The MVC 2 RTM binary is unstable on some prerelease versions of the .NET 4 Framework, which your host is likely running.

Comment: I took your suggestion and they completed the re-install (updated output in the question), and now the version numbers match - yet the problem is still present...?

Comment: There might still be multiple conflicting copies of the MVC binary loaded.  Please follow the instructions at http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/diagnosing-aspnet-mvc-problems.html and update your question with the output from that particular diagnostic tool.

Drop the .aspx file into your application, reproduce the error, then browse directly to the .aspx file (it's just a regular WebForms page).  Remember to delete the .aspx when you're done.

Comment: Diagnostics data added.  Looks pretty innocent as far as I can tell though.  MVC RTM appears to be present.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the hint path and specific version

```
<Reference 
Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, 
processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```